# "Today" in Spoken Singaporean Mandarin

Tags: spoken

Is "今日" or "今天" more appropriate to use when speaking Singaporean Mandarin? Is it different than the one that is used in writing?

Comment: I believe @杨以轩 is from Singapore? He may be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good overview on the distinctive features of [Singaporean Mandarin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singaporean_Mandarin). In Singapore's context, there is nothing unique pertaining to the usage of "今日" and "今天". 今日 is more formal and is used more often where today means "nowadays" while 今天 is usually used where today means "this present day", both in speech and writing.

The following examples demonstrate the difference in usage for these similar words:

> 在**今日**的西方社会，同性恋已不再是罪错。
>  Homosexuality is no longer viewed as a crime
>   in today's western society.
>
> **今天**的天气真好！
>  Today's weather is great!

Answer (score 2):

今天 is both the right answer for speaking and writing in modern society.

今日 is more in drama of old time story.

Comment: "In modern society" doesn't mean "in modern Singapore society", so this doesn't actually answer OP's question.

Comment: Sking, can you elaborate more on your answer?